# Mailgun unsubscribe text in email

Tags: cpanel, mailgun, whm

So i have recently added and verified my mailgun account to my DNS & configured it through Exim through (WHM) on my server using the following guide.

[enter link description here](https://grepitout.com/configure-mailgun-cpanel-exim/)

It is now tracking my emails which is what i wanted, However on creating a new account through WHM and logging into the webmail into the new account i sent a test email to myself and i have at the bottom of the email "To unsubscribe click *LINK*"

As I'll be providing clients emails who will need to use emails daily i wouldn't want this link being under every single email they send.

I have upgraded my account, as i believed this would stop it but it hasn't?

Could anybody throw some light on this situation.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to Mailgun, click your Domain Name and then disable the "Unsubscribes" option. This will then remove the link that is being automatically added to your outgoing emails.